# how to add static to my scripts in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

i have a datetimepicker created in js, but i have a little problem adding a static tag to my base.html,if i do, i wont get what i want or what i have written in my js its just rendering a normal html,i want it to be in a way in which once clicked it shows the date and time as stated in my js, here is what i have tried, everything is working perfectly except the date and time picker[[image: here is the view]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRjNO.jpg)

## **base.html**

##header

```
 {% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}Jazeera{% endblock title %}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block meta %}welcome to jazeera medical healthcare {% endblock meta %}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   {% block all %}
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/ionicons.min.css' %}">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icomoon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">

  </head>
```

##footer

```
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/scrollax.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}" type="c9dfb692cab9a2d000c13798-text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.timepicker.min.js' %}" type="c9dfb692cab9a2d000c13798-text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/google-map.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.backstretch.min.js' %}"></script>
```

[image: here is the displayed picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it,i added it in plain,and added some styles to it my self

```
 <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.timepicker.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following steps:

1- check your `settings` to find out that everything is in the right place, something like this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

2- use Developer Tools (`F12`) to check if static files loaded, do not forget to restart server.

3- make sure the page you are using to create `datetime` has access to the parent template, in case your are inheriting, something like this :

```
other.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

4- put your static files in a block on top of your page `base.html` then add to this block from other inherited page (if you implemented like what I said in step 3) below could be an example :

```
base.html

{% block head %}
    .......
{% endblock head %}

other.html

{% block head %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.js' %}" type="c9dfb692cab9a2d000c13798-text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.timepicker.min.js' %}" type="c9dfb692cab9a2d000c13798-text/javascript"></script>
{% endblock head %}
```

5- check you have following on top of your page:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
```

And do not forget that some `libs` have dependency that must be called before calling other `libs`, order of calling is important.

Comment: thanks for the kind explanation with full details,but i have all you mentioned set up,the problem is from adding type = "c9dfb692cab9a2d000c13798-text/javascript",if i remove it i will get the pop up calendar and time but wont be styled nor well arranged,if their is a way i can add static to that type it will be great and helpful